# jQuery : JSONP : Execute Received Info

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm using JSONP to get data from a server.

The more typical method of dealing with this is to get the data and then have the javascript determine what to do with the data (updating a div, etc)

However, instead of responding with simple data, the server is responding with the actual jQuery code that needs to be executed.  How can I make my javascript accept that response and then actually execute it?  I've done this very successfully with Mootools (using evalScripts), but I can't figure it out in jQuery.

The benefits of this is that the client side code is much smaller and less work has to be done in the browser.

Example:

```
$.getJSON("http://appbeacon.com/index.php?model=blah_blah_blah", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        console.log(item);
        // Need to execute "item" ??????
    });
});
```

Example Response (No Longer JSON Encoded):

```
$("#1_cmd_group").remove();
$("#2_cmd_group").remove();
$("#3_contents").html("<li>blah blah blah");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval(item);
```

give that a go

Comment: JSON is not meant to be code.  You should view it interchangeably with XML.

Comment: Thank you.  That was a lot easier than I expected.  I edited my original post with the Mootools method of doing this, then it dawned on me to search google for "jquery evalScripts".  I came up with several convoluted solutions.  
Your answer was right on.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Glad I could help. Just one note however. eval() is relatively slow compared to executing normal code so just be cautious when using it.